# llvm: cannot run doxygen

Tags: llvm

I can't build docs.

I am doing all things in llvm source directory.

```
./configure --enable-doxygen
make
...
llvm[1]: Building doxygen documentation
error: configuration file /media/data/virtual/share/gsoc/llvm/docs/doxygen.cfg not found!
...
make[1]: *** [regendoc] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/media/data/virtual/share/gsoc/llvm/docs'
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to make a `make clean` and retry. PS: What gsoc is yours?

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

I have no ida, but you might try to create configuration file on your own, for example with

```
doxywizard
```